# using javascript pompt when closing page

Tags: prompt, onbeforeunload

I work with **onbeforeunload** to display a message with text area when closing pages, the problem is I am getting the message but not the text. The code I am using is :

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
                var response = prompt("Whay this page isn't good for YOU ?", "");
                //put the response in log file 
                //Exit the page 
            });
```

i tried so hard to get the prompt but no result.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually short hand it using `window.onbeforeunload = yourfunction` and then create your function which prompts the user.

**EDIT**

Apologies, it seems as though ASP.NET is allowing me to do something a bit weird, it seems like the easiest way to go about this is to append your function at the end of that as such: `window.onbeforeunload = function(){ return "Say what you want!" }` This will display a prompt before the window is closing, I'm sure you can replace it for whatever you like.